# Magento 2 load product media images by store id

Tags: media, magento2, image-gallery

I have 3 store views created in Magneto 2.

1) NL

2) EN

3) EN B2B

There are 10,000 products. Products details is fine in NL and EN store.

But in **EN B2B** store i can see images of NL store as well. And i can not remove images one by one from 10,000 products.

So i am trying to changes code in Gallery.php to load images of EN store in EN B2B store.

In Gallery.php file this function is loading all media images,

```
public function getGalleryImages()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
        if ($images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                /* @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject $image */
                $image->setData(
                    'small_image_url',
                    $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
                $image->setData(
                    'medium_image_url',
                    $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')
                        ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
                $image->setData(
                    'large_image_url',
                    $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')
                        ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
            }
        }

        return $images;
    }
```

But i am not getting how to pass store id to load images from specific store view.

Comment: have you thought instead to try removing unwanted images from products programmatically?

Comment: I want to load EN store product images instead of EN B2B

Comment: @Hardik have you got any solution ?